# Automatically click a link to download an mp3 file recorded with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

My page uses getUserMedia in the same way as a JSFiddle I found, so I will link to it for simplicity's sake: https://jsfiddle.net/sasivarunan/bv55z5fe/

I've tried to use this jQuery:

```
  $('#audioDownload').click();
```

in my stopRecord.onclick function in order to automatically click the link and download the mp3 once the recording stops, but it's not working.  I also tried using

```
  document.getElementById("audioDownload").click();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Yusril's answer wasn't working for me, this addition did solve my problem:

```
recordedAudio.onloadeddata = e => {
  document.getElementById("audioDownload").click();
}
```

with recordedAudio being the actual mp3 and audioDownload being the link.  This must mean that the mp3 is not ready to be downloaded immediately after the stopRecord button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
$("#audioDownload").get(0).click();
```

I have tested it in your code and it works:
https://jsfiddle.net/bv55z5fe/97/

Comment: What browser are you using? It's not working in Chrome.

Comment: @MichaelThompson I use Chrome Version 61.0.3163.100. But first, you need to give permission for recording to the browser. Here is the screenshot of it: https://ibb.co/hWfAkw

Comment: The browser is automatically accepting the microphone, so that's not the issue.  I found another way to solve my problem, but thank you anyway!